# Prove that $\operatorname{Var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2=\sigma^2dt$ with $\mathbb{E}[X]:=p(u-d)+d$

Tags: probability, exponential-function, expected-value, variance

I have to prove that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2=\sigma^2dt$ for $\mathbb{E}[X]:=p(u-d)+d$ as from title, and with:

- $p:=\frac{e^{rdt}-d}{u-d}$;
- $u:=e^{\sigma\sqrt{dt}}$;
- $d:=e^{-\sigma\sqrt{dt}}$.

I arrive to say that $e^{r\sigma dt\sqrt{dt}}+e^{-r \sigma dt \sqrt{dt}}-1-e^{2rdt}$ but now I'm stuck. How can I continue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you want the steps ? I am asking because in general, $\text{Var}[X]=\Bbb E[X^2]-\Bbb E[X]^2$ is valid.

Comment: @Souza My text says that $\operatorname{Var}[X]=pu^2+(1−p)d^2−[pu+(1−p)d]^2=σ^2dt$ with the conditions on $p,u,d$ like above, but I only arrive to prove that $\operatorname{Var}[X]=e^{r \sigma dt \sqrt{dt}}+e^{−r \sigma dt \sqrt{dt}}−1−e^{2rdt}$. So yes, if it's possibile the steps that start from here.

Comment: @Souza To be clear, please see here: https://books.google.it/books?id=njXiBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA387&dq=options+futures+and+other+derivatives+variable+a+is+sometimes+called+growth+factors&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI-Y60scjsAhUkREEAHdExAVIQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg